# MVVM light how view model is instantiated

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm-light

I have a wpf application and am using mvvm light toolkit for my databinding.  I havea parent view has a datagrid of the parents and the child control has a child grid for the children of the selected parent that access the same view model.  The parent and children are syncing well in the view model so I am not including the code.  The problem is this:  When the child control is bound as follows:

```
  <UserControl.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="jobRequirementViewSource"
                          d:DesignSource="{d:DesignInstance {x:Type Models:JobRequirement}, CreateList=True}"/>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:jobViewModel}">
        <views:jrView/>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Everything works as expected and the child grid syncs with the parent view through the code in the view model.  When the binding in the child grid is a follows:

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <Binding Path="jobViewModel" Source="{StaticResource Locator}"/>
</UserControl.DataContext>
```

Then apparently a new instance of the view model is created and the child grid is not synced with the instance of the parent grid's view model.  I am using the view model locator and instance is created in the locator.  The view model is initiated in the locators constructor with the following line:
     SimpleIoc.Default.Register();
and includes the view model constructor as per examples in mvvm light
            public jobViewModel jobViewModel
        {  get
            {return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance(); }
        }
Why is the second instance of the view model created when the data context of the child control is set using the UserControl.DataContext binding?

Answer (score 1):

> Why is the second instance of the view model created when the data context of the child control is set using the UserControl.DataContext binding?

Because the `ViewModelLocator` creates a new instance of the view model during the first call to `ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<jobViewModel>()`.

Every object resolved by the `ViewModelLocator` in MvvmLight is a singleton by default so you should make sure that you use the `ViewModelLocator` to create *all* instances of the `jobViewModel` class throughout your application, i.e. do this:

```
var x = new ViewModel.ViewModelLocator();
var vm = x.jobViewModel;
```

...instead of this:

```
var vm = new jobViewModel();
```

...when you instantiate the `jobViewModel` in the parent view model or wherever you instantiate it.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  It took me a while but I found the error in my code as you stated above.  The Parent view was bound to a viewmodel created by code which bypassed the viewmodel locator (as you showed).  Therefore when I bound the xaml of the child view to the locator it was using a different instance of the viewmodel (created by the locator), but binding the child view via the datacontext bound it to the instance of the view model used by the parent view.